# Multicast without going through the primary gateway?

Tags: routes, udp, multicast

I'm trying to use [uFTP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/uftp-multicast/) to distribute build files through our internal network. In theory this should be fine because I don't need to broadcast this out through the internet or through routers, because everyone is on the same switch.

The problem seems to be that it seems to want to route all the traffic through the primary gateway (which happens to be a dinky consumer router that *apparently* uses a 100 Mb interface internally or something, despite having gigabit ports on both sides).

Thing is, (again) this should be all local traffic, so why are my computers shoving the multicast through the router at all? As far as I've been able to find on the internet, you don't need a router whatsoever if it's all on the same local area network (like I'm doing).

Do I have to set up routes on all the target machine or something? Everywhere I read says this should all be working out of the box, so I don't know what is going on...

Comment: Are you using the `-t` option on the server (i.e. sender)?  That specifies the multicast TTL.  Any value other than the default of 1 can result in packets being sent outside the local LAN.

Comment: No, the current command line is `uftp.exe -C "tfmcc:min=500:max=9900000" -b 1000 -M ff02::3:2:3 -P ff02::6:5:6 -z -S xmitstats_%BUILD_NUMBER%.log -m 10 -x 2 -p 1045 "D:\Shared\PerCommitBuildsStaging\%DirToPullFrom%\WindowsNoEditor"`, which seems to work as IPv6 isn't enabled on the router (so I'm assuming it just doesn't even try to handle it)

Comment: Are the receivers getting multicast traffic from the server at least?  Running Wireshark on the receivers should confirm this.  Also check for any software firewall on the receivers.

Comment: Yes, communication is happening, just at 100 Mbps max (nowhere near the gigabit these things are capable, and they are because transferring via SMB works fine point-to-point). And during the transfer, the router itself gets IO contention up to 3.0 in the TOP utility.